# Как сделать фигуру (трапецию) на CSS?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать такую фигуру на CSS и HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 300px;
}
.block {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(104, 144, 231, 1);
}
.block:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: -50px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 50px solid rgba(104, 144, 231, 1);
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
}
.block:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  right: -50px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 50px solid rgba(104, 144, 231, 1);
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

[Подробнее про геометрические фигуры на CSS](http://habrahabr.ru/post/126207/)
Про псевдоэлементы [:before](http://htmlbook.ru/css/before), [:after](http://htmlbook.ru/css/after)

Про FlexBox: на [русском](http://frontender.info/a-guide-to-flexbox/) и [английском](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 9):

Смотря для чего нужна эта фигура, возможен еще такой вариант:

```css
.shape {
  width: 240px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #6890E7;
  margin: auto;
  transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```